# Make decisions based on values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an an associative array which I have sorted in ascending order and now I want to make some decisions on those values. I can't understand how should I proceed.

Let me explain what I want to achieve:

**Suppose:** I have the following raw array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cell] => b2
            [sign] => &#10008;
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [cell] => a1
            [sign] => &#9711;
        )
)
```

which then I sorted it as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cell] => a1
            [sign] => &#9711;
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [cell] => b2
            [sign] => &#10008;
        )
)
```

Now I want to make decisions such as whether the values of cells `a1 = b1 = c1` or `a1 = b2 = c3` etc. Now how can I do that?

Comment: "I want to make decisions such as whether the values of cells a1 = b1 = c1 or a1 = b2 = c3 etc." I don't exactly know what you mean can you elaborate a bit

Comment: To be elaborate, its a tic tac toe game. So I want to make decisions based on the inputted values. And the inputted values are in that array.

Comment: To be more elaborate, suppose the users has clicked on a1, b2 and c3 cells, which is the diagonal from the left, then I need to check whether those cells have the same values in order to declare the winner.

Comment: So when the values of cell a1 equals cell b1 and equals c1 you want to do something?

Comment: Exactly, and not only those 3 cells, all the other cell combinations which is required to declare winners.

Comment: Aaah, noughts and crosses.

Comment: exactly, hehe..my first attempt for a tiny game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134012/discussion-between-ayan-and-sander-visser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more generalized implementation in Javascript. It is only tested on 2x2 and 3x3 game states, may need debugging for other game sizes:

```js
// xxx
// oo-
// o--  
alert("game a: " + WhoIsWinningGeneratePaths('xxxoo-o--'));


// x-x
// oo-
// o--  
alert("game b: " + WhoIsWinningGeneratePaths('x-xoo-o--'));

// x-x
// ooo
// ---  
alert("game c: " + WhoIsWinningGeneratePaths('x-xooo---'));

// x-
// oo  
alert("game d: " + WhoIsWinningGeneratePaths('x-oo'));

// x-
// ox  
alert("game e: " + WhoIsWinningGeneratePaths('x-ox'));


// x-
// o-  
alert("game f: " + WhoIsWinningGeneratePaths('x-o-'));


function WhoIsWinningGeneratePaths(state) {

  var n = Math.sqrt(state.length);

  var rows = IsWin(state, GenPaths(n, 0,     1,   n, n));
  var cols = IsWin(state, GenPaths(n, 0,     n,   1, n));
  var diUp = IsWin(state, GenPaths(1, n-1, n-1,   0, n));
  var diDn = IsWin(state, GenPaths(1, 0,   n+1,   0, n));

  if (rows !== '-') return rows;
  if (cols !== '-') return cols;
  if (diUp !== '-') return diUp;
  return diDn;

}

function GenPaths(count, start, incrementA, incrementB, lengthToWin) {
  var paths = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var path = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < lengthToWin; j++) {
      path.push(start + i * incrementB + j * incrementA)
    }
    paths.push(path);
  }
  return paths;
}


function IsWin(state, paths) {
  for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    var currentPathResult = IsPathWin(state, paths[i]);
    if (currentPathResult != '-')
      return currentPathResult;
  }
  return '-';
}

function IsPathWin(state, path) {
  var first = state[path[0]];
  for (var j = 1; j < path.length; j++)
  {
    var compareToFirst = state[path[j]];
    if (compareToFirst !== first)
      return '-';
  }
  return first;
}
```

Comment: can you explain this code to me as I need to improve it to account for some changes like check for 3 signs in a line for grids 4*4, 4 signs for 5*5 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that your square is only **3x3**, I would say the most simplest way would be to store the winning matches inside an array and just compare them by using `array_intersect()` which combines two arrays and returns the duplicated values in an array. To get the number of duplicates, just wrap the `count()` function and compare if player one or two's values have matched the `$winArr`. Obviously there's still work to do by stopping duplicate values for your input array, Looping your `foreach()` after each input etc... but at least your logic will be correct.

```
$winner; //Winner --> Used when game finished

$winArr = [

    ['c1','c2','c3'], 
    ['b1','b2','b3'], // --> Vertical Win
    ['a1','a2','a3'],

    ['a1','b2','c3'],
    ['c1','b2','c3'], // --> Diagonal Win

    ['a1','b1','c1'],
    ['a2','b2','c2'], // --> Horizontal Win
    ['a3','b3','c3'],

];

$gameArr = [ // --> `Input Values Array = Dimension for P1 & P2 for ease

'playerOne' => ['a1', 'b1', 'c2', 'c1'],
'playerTwo' => ['a3', 'b3', 'a2'],    

];



foreach ($winArr as $k=>$v) {

    if (count(array_intersect($v, $gameArr['playerOne'])) === 3) {

        $winner = 'Player One!';       
        break;

    } elseif(count(array_intersect($v, $gameArr['playerTwo'])) === 3) {

        $winner = 'Player Two!';
        break;

    }

}

if (isset($winner)) {

    echo $winner;

}
```

**Output:**

```
Player One!
```

**See:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: that means I need to change my current array structure with the $gameArr structure? Can't it be done with the structure I have.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest referring to the positions of cells by a zero-based index. It makes it easy to use math tricks, like modulo or integer division to select rows or columns. Otherwise, you have to use a ton of offsets to avoid off-by-one errors.

IE, the board could be labeled:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

The game state can be represented with a character array, with character '-' meaning empty, and x and o meaning x and o played there.

Here is a human game view, and the game stored in a string array:

```
  x
o x o
o x

var state = "-x-oxoox-";
```

To check if a game has been won, lets make a function.

the function returns '-' if no one won, 'x' if x won, and 'o' if o won.

I am going to start you off with a implementation that hard codes every path to check. Then I show how to generate the paths to check.

```
function WhoIsWinningHardCode(state) {

  var rows     = IsWin(state, [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]);
  var cols     = IsWin(state, [[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8]]);
  var diagUp   = IsWin(state, [[6,4,2]]);
  var diagDown = IsWin(state, [[0,4,8]]);

  if (rows     !== '-') return rows;
  if (cols     !== '-') return cols;
  if (diagUp   !== '-') return diagUp;
  return diagDown;

}

function WhoIsWinningGeneratePaths(state) {

  var rows     = IsWin(state, GenPaths(3, 0, 1, 3));
  var cols     = IsWin(state, GenPaths(3, 0, 3, 1));
  var diagUp   = IsWin(state, GenPaths(1, 2, 2, 0));
  var diagDown = IsWin(state, GenPaths(1, 0, 4, 0));

  if (rows     !== '-') return rows;
  if (cols     !== '-') return cols;
  if (diagUp   !== '-') return diagUp;
  return diagDown;

}

function GenPaths(count, start, incrementA, incrementB) {
   var paths = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      var path = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
         path.push(start + i*incrementB + j*incrementA)
      }
      paths.push(path);
   }
   return paths;
}

function IsWin(state, paths) {
  for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
     var path = paths[i];
     var a = state[path[0]];
     var b = state[path[1]];
     var c = state[path[2]];
     if (a !== '-')
       if (a == b)
         if (a == c)
           return a;
  }

  return '-';
}
```

Comment: the `genPaths` should work for grids more than 3X3 also. Right?

Comment: Almost -- the hard-coded number '3' in GenPaths would need to be put into a variable that is passed as a parameter. That three is basically saying "a winning path in a 3 by 3 game is 3 long". For example, in a 6 by 6 game, it a winning path would need to be 6 long.

Comment: have you tested it? In order to use your code I have to restructure a lot many things, so I am asking before proceeding.

Comment: I have not tested or run it at all. Also, it is in javascript, and I think you are using PHP. If you don't mind using javascript, it can be tested pretty easily using a code sandbox like https://jsfiddle.net/ .

Comment: IsWin is currently hardcoded to check 3 points on the path as well. To generalize, IsWin can be changed to index into each point along a variable path length for equality, by using a for loop with path.length bound.

Comment: Can you generalize it for me, it would be a great help as I not well versed with js.

Comment: Btw in the `genPaths` what is incrementA and incrementB for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134024/discussion-between-william-and-ayan).